# Segmentation fault at initializing the object

Tags: c++, linux

```
Class vector
{
    int *v ;
    int size;
    public:

    vector(int m ) // create a null vector
    {
        v=new int[size = m];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            v[i]=0;
    }

    vector(int *a) //create a vector from an array
    {
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            v[i]=a[i];
    }

    int operator*(vector &y) //scalar product
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            sum+=this->v[i]*y-v[i];
        return sum;
    }
}; 


int main()
{
    int x[3]={1,2,3};
    int y[3]={4,5,6};
    vector v1(3); //create a null vector of 3 integers
    vector v2(3);
    v1=x; //create v1 from the array x
    v2=y;

    int R=v1*v2;
    cout<<”R=”r;
    return 0;
}
```

After executing above program i am getting segmentation fault at this point("v1=x";)
Can any one please explain why i am getting segmentation fault.

Comment: `v1=x; //create v1 from the array x` you're not creating `v1`, you're assigning a value to it.

Comment: There's at least 2 typos in the code. Please, always copy-paste the code which reproduces the issue rather than type it in by sight.

Comment: I'm curious, is there any reason for not using standard library's containers ? Or is just that you don't know about them ? All you will get with that kind of code is waist your time: modern C++ discourages using raw pointers and handling memory yourself (besides not reinventing the wheel).

Comment: This question is about a mathematical vector not a vector container. otherwise the scalar product would not make any sense.

Comment: @BDL Ah, yep, sorry, didn't see the product. But still, this shouldn't be handled that way. At least encapsulate a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you construct your `vector` from an `int*` you don't set the `size` but you access its value. This constructor is used for the implicit conversion from `int*` to `vector` needed for the assignment. Accessing an uninitialized value causes the program to have undefined behavior. Most likely the `size` has some value result effectively in an some inaccessible memory to be accessed.

The fact that you have set the left hand side of the assignment to have a specific size doesn't help. It *could* help if you defined your own assignment from `int*` to `vector`:

```
vector& vector= (int* other) {
     // ...
}
```

Having this assignment operator (with a suitable implementation, of course) would avoid the implicit conversion from `int*` to `vector` and you could use the `size` of the left hand side.

This is by far not the only program with your code:

- You allocate memory but you never release it. If you allocate memory in a constructor you'll need a destructor to release the memory.
- Of course, once you do you'll easily release memory multiple times because you don't have a copy constructor or a copy assignment and the compiler generated versions do a flat copy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way how your memory is allocated. Let us only look at these four lines:

```
vector v1(3); //create a null vector of 3 integers
v1=x; //create v1 from the array x
```

In the first line, a new object v1 is created by using the vector(int m) constructor form. Here a new int array is allocated on the heap.

In the third line a new object is created, replacing the one assigned in line 1. And here the problems start, since this line uses the vector(int *a) constructor that does neither allocate the v array, nor does it set the size variable. Thus you copy the input to a not allocated address which causes the stack fault. In addition, you never release the memory allocated in the first line's constructor.

Other problems with your code:
In the *-operator you multiply an int with a vector

```
sum += this->v[i] * y - v[i];
                  ^^^
```

although this multiplication operator is not defined.

This line will also not compile:

```
cout<<”R=”r;
```

First because of the missing << between "R=" and r, and then because of the strange ”.